# What is the difference between the words "clear", "transparent" and "obvious"?

Tags: vocabulary, word-difference

I would appreciate it if you could tell me the difference between the words "clear", "transparent" and "obvious".

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I think you want to learn these three words when we talk about some 'matter'. Certainly, more context would help get you precise answers but here is something that might help you.

When the matter is clear, most of the times, the results are 'known' to everyone and there's **no** doubt. If runner 'A' is 10 km ahead to rest of the runners in the Marathon, it's quite *clear* that he'll win (unless some miracle happens).

Transparency denotes 'clear and open' to everyone. If the matter is transparent, it's known to everyone. You don't need to ponder over the matter. It's not a mystery to solve, it's 'transparent'.

Obviousness talks about 'certainty'. If the matter is obvious, it's quite certain. It's **obvious** that if one team in football wins, the other one loses. You cannot call it 'transparent' or 'clear'.

More context will be helpful but to make you understand these three *broadly*, I typed down my answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could add that 'transparency' is usually used in the context of  certain **processes**; for example, your government could be working transparently, but it is not 'transparent' why a cat catches a mouse, even though that's no mystery to solve. So, there's a necessity that it **could** be a secret.

Comment: @sanchises I tried to be narrow and specific. However, your point is good.

Comment: I know, other than that I think your answer is very clear and concise, but I considered 'transparent' to be a little bit of the odd one out here, since things that are 'clear' *can* be 'obvious' sometimes and vice versa, but the same does not go for transparency.

Comment: @sanchises - Although if we are talking about windows and shower doors, those that are "clear" are also "transparent" and vice-versa – yet "obvious" would not apply. Perhaps I'm just stating the obvious, but I thought it was worth mentioning how a thesaurus would probably list both _obvious_ and _transparent_ under synonyms for _clear_ (and I wonder if that's what motivated the question; too bad the O.P. didn't delve into that.)

Comment: That's why I said 'matter' in my very first line. @J.R.

Comment: That's why my comment was directed at sanchises' comment, MaulikV :-)