# How is 'prowl' different from 'move around'?

Tags: word-difference

Does 'prowl' mean the same as 'move around'?

> - He **prowled** the street at night.
> - He **moved around** the street at night.

Do these two sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: I'm sorry, but [just about every dictionary I checked](http://www.onelook.com/?w=prowl&ls=a) explained this pretty clearly. If you already looked this word up in a dictionary, and are still confused for some reason, then, [**please**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439), paste the definition here, and explain in more detail why you are still confused.

Comment: All right... I get the meaning of 'prowl' in a dictionary, but it's hard to catch the difference in its connotation like move around and prowl because English is not my native language.  So I don't think it's just a matter of checking it in a dictionary or not.

Comment: I checked 'word-difference' and found tons of questions like my questions ( what's the difference between ... kind of questions )  Why is only my question banned???

Comment: @Akihiro, if you post what you found, we know what you understood and can answer accordingly. And no, putting questions on hold that dont do so is standard procedure - you didn't find them because they often are deleted after a short time. You are *very* welcome to edit your post and ask for a better/different explanation than what your dictionary gave you. Compare [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65534/the-difference-between-to-fry-and-to-braise) and [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54280/what-is-the-difference-between-the-words-clear-transparent-and-obvious).

Comment: @Akihiro - Your question has not been "banned," it has been put "on hold." That means it can be reopened if you make it more fitting for the site. As for those "tons of questions" you found, how many of them had more than one or two upvotes? Low-quality quesitons are often a problem on this site. Instead of comparing your question to several mediocre questions, it would be better to learn how to write a good one.  Did you read [THIS](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) yet? Pay particular attention to Matt's answer there, too.

Comment: @Stephie - Great comment; there's still time to run for moderator :-) As for good examples of word-difference questions, I'd also point Akihiro and others to [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54882), which was also in danger of being put on hold, until the OP added some clarifying remarks, which were [graciously edited into the question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/54882/revisions) by TJY.

Comment: Yes, I read yours.  You mean I should edit mine that had already been posted?  Or can I just leave it and post some better and fitting ones later?

Comment: @Akihiro, yes the best way to handle this now is to go to a dictionary, and look up _prowl_. Then, if that hasn't answered  your question, do two things: (1) Paste that definition into this question, so that everyone knows you have researched this, and (2) explain why that definition doesn't answer your question (in other words, say why you are still confused, or why you need more clarification than the dictionary provides). Do those two things, and this will become a model question instead of an on-hold question. If you ask your future questions in that same way, you'll earn more rep faster.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  Just one more thing.  Is any dictionary ok?  The one I usually use is not so in details explained.

Comment: I recommend looking the word up in two or three dictionaries ([OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=prowl&ls=a) is a great place to start), but you would only need to post definitiions from one dictionary in your question. Pick the one that was most helpful to you – that will probably be the most helpful to us, too!

Comment: @Akihiro Basically any dictionary is ok, but you would do *youself* a favour if you choose a "good" one. There are many options, even online and for free and most of us have their preferences. A dictionary that simply translates "word A -> word B" is dangerous because you only rarely can translate 1:1. If you can understand English well enough (and it seems so), try a monolingual one that doesn't translate but explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Prowl* is typically used of animals moving about seeking prey, so to say somebody "prowled the streets" implies that he moved about stealthily, keeping to the shadows and seeking some target—perhaps for nefarious purposes.